# Which scripture talks about 'Hreem' bija mantra other than Devi bhagvatam? I am talking about Hreem/Devi Pranava/Tantrokt Paranava

Tags: sin, devi, durga, devi-bhagavata-purana

In devi bhagvat I saw some description of Devi Pranava Hreem.But those were not sufficient. I want to know the power of Hreem. And what does it can do.

I want to destroy all of my sins of every birth. How much crores of Hreem mantra jap shall be sufficient for this?

Comment: Matters related to mantra-shastra aren't meant to be discussed in public forums like this. Besides if you truly want to reedem your sins of past births, then I would suggest to take baths in sacred rivers (especially in the Ganga) or observe fasts.

Comment: Hrim is one of the bija mantras from the tantras (agamas). Hrim is the Maya bija. The power of a bija mantra is imparted to one by their guru.